How should independent random variables be distributed to have their product be distributed as a gaussian?
The title of the question says it all!
Given $N$ independent random variables distributed in the same way
$$X_1,X_2,...,X_N$$
how can they be distributed to have their product $P$
$$P=\prod _{i=1}^N X_i$$
be distributed as a gaussian (a.k.a. normal distribution)?
Bonus points for an answer that includes the mean and variance of the resulting gaussian (I am particularly interested in the result being a gaussian with mean zero).

Perhaps first study the case $N=2$.

The answer for the iid case is given in (2) of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09838

If $X$ has a normal distribution with mean $0$, we can write $X = S \exp(L)$ where $S = \pm 1$, each with probability $1/2$, and $S$ and $L$ are independent.  The product of $n$ iid random variables $S_i$ with the distribution of $S$ also has this distribution.  If we can
find iid random variables $L_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n L_i$ has the distribution of $L$, then $X_i = S_i \exp(L_i)$ are iid and $$\prod_{i=1}^n X_i = \left(\prod_{i=1}^n S_i\right) \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n L_i \right)$$ has the
distribution of $X$.  I don't know if this works, but if it does the characteristic function of $L_i$ is an $n$'th root of the characteristic function of $L$.

Here is a partial answer inspired by Robert Israel's idea.
Actually, computations will turn out to be carried more easily easier with a positive random variable, that is why we will consider the sign of the normal variable $N \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ as a separate random variable; let's denote it by $S = \operatorname{sgn} N$. Since the normal distribution is symmetric around its mean and a fortiori the associated centered variable possesses an even distribution, $N-\mu$ will be positive and negative respectively half of the time, in such a way that $S$ is equally distributed and may be written as $S = 2B-1$, where $B$ is a standard Bernoulli variable.
Now, it is possible to reparametrize the centered version of your problem, namely $N-\mu = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$, by writing the iid $X_i$ as $X_i = S_iY_i$, where $Y_i$ are positive $S_i$ are distributed in the same way as $S$ above and are independent of $Y_i$. Given that $S = \prod_{i=1}^n S_i$, our problem is simplified to $Z := |N-\mu| = \prod_{i=1}^n Y_i$, where $Z$ is nothing else than a unilateral normal variable.
Usually, when a sum appears instead of the product on the right hand side, we would compute and compare the characteristic functions of the given variables, as suggested by Robert Israel in his answer. However, in the present case, it would require to transform the product into a sum with the help of an exponential and, then, to determine the characteristic function of the exponential of a normal distribution $-$ which is not log-normal ! $-$, before inverse Fourier transforming the $n^\mathrm{th}$ root of the result. The computations are likely to be tedious.
Actually, it is possible to "cheat" a little bit by replacing the Fourier transform of the characteristic function by a Mellin transform, because the latter observes a multiplicative analog of the convolution theorem, recalling that the density functions of the $Y_i$ are multiplicatively convoluted. In consequence, the "multiplicative characteristic funtion" of $Z$, i.e. the Mellin transform of $f_Z$, denoted here by $$M_Z(t) := \mathcal{M}[f_Z(z)](s) = \Bbb{E}[Z^{s-1}] = \int_0^\infty z^{s-1} f_Z(z) \,\mathrm{d}z,$$ is just the product of the Mellin transform of each $f_Y$, i.e. $M_Z(s) = \prod_{i=1}^n M_{Y_i}(s) = M_Y(s)^n$, since the $Y_i$ are iid, hence $f_Y(y) = \mathcal{M}^{-1}[M_Z(s)^{1/n}](y)$ in the end by inversion of the Mellin transform.
Nevertheless, we still need to find the Mellin transform of a half-normal distribution. Given that the generalized gaussian $e^{-x^p}$ is mapped to $\mathcal{M}[e^{-x^p}](s) = \frac{1}{p}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{p}\right)$, one obtains :
$$
M_z(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} z^{s-1}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) 
       = \frac{(2\sigma^2)^{s/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \mathcal{M}[e^{-z^2}](s) 
       = \frac{(2\sigma^2)^{s/2}}{2\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)
$$
I'm not sure whether it is possible to work out a nice closed form, but, at the very least, you have now a formal solution with an integral representation at your disposal.

Since $Z^2$ is Gamma distributed when $Z\sim N(0,1)$, with shape parameter $1/2$ and since the log of a Gamma variable is infinitely divisible, the answer is  easy. More specifically, if $Y$ is Gamma with shape parameter $a$ then we have
$$E(Y^s)=\frac{\Gamma(a+s)}{\Gamma(a)}=\frac{a}{a+s}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{s}{a+n}}e^{s/n}$$ Now if $\Pr(U>u)=e^{-u}$ consider the independent rv $V_0,V_1,\ldots$ such that $V_n\sim \frac{1}{n}-\frac{U}{a+n}$ and $V_0\sim -U/a$ then $\log Y\sim \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}V_n$ Since each $V_n$ is infinitely divisible this is also the case for $\log Y$.
Coming back to the normal rv $Z$ for fixed $k$ we know now that we can write $|Z|\sim Y_1\ldots Y_k$ where $\log Y_1,\ldots, \log Y_k$ are iid and Gamma distributed of shape parameter $1/2k.$ To solve the question of the sign, just now consider $\epsilon _i=\pm 1$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$  independent and independent of $Y_1,\ldots,Y_k$ and consider $Y'_i=\epsilon _iY_i$.  Then we get $Z\sim  Y'_1\ldots Y'_k$ as desired.
